# ng-class not working on condition true upon ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing an issue with ng-class where if i click am passing a variable and checking it in ng-class whether it is true or not ,if its true then i am appending "col-xs-6" class.

I have tried something here

```
<div ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar}">
<div class="panel panel-default panel-height" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails track by $index">
    <div class="panel-heading header-background">
        <div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" class="stop-watch"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="pull-right">{{candidateInfo.name}}</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-9"><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="myVar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+toggle}}">{{candidateInfo.name}} resume</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="{{toggle}}" class="collapse" ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar}">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

but this is not working

I have no idea where i am going wrong

I have infact tried it in plunker as well [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4wIh4Y8RZUX1YdDeHvon?p=preview)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: yes i have tried giving it a value as
ng-click="myVar='true'" 
and in ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar=='true'}" but it is not working

Comment: Your plunker has an issue with Angular2. Try with a different version

Answer (score 3):

You are using angular 2.0 and writing code for angulat 1.5 .change your library to angular 1

Also your myvar is not defined inside the scope , its always going to b falsy

Comment: so for this i need to call a function there and in controller i need to define $scope.myVar="something"
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely.
$scope.myVar = true;//or false
or toggle it via some click handler

Answer (score 2):

you will have to make it like below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Bx9s88ASSxGkgJDj0U0L?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div >
<div ng-class="{'col-md-6': myVar == true}">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading header-background">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="pull-right">John</a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-9"><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="myVar=true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+toggle}}">John resume</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="{{toggle}}"  ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar == true}">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

and in script

```
 $scope.toggle = "accor"
         $scope.myvar = false;
```

Note : i have chnage the class from col-xs-6 to col-md-6 , since i am working on a laptop.If you are checking this on mobile col-xs-6 will work similar way.